# Wrap every 4 divs - wrong behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using the code below to wrap every 4 divs with class .wrap4 inside a div with class .wrapList

**Js code:**

```
function Wrap(){
        var $children = $('.wrap4');
        for(var i = 0, l = $children.length; i < l; i += 4) {
            $children.slice(i, i+4).wrapAll('<div class="wrapList"></div>');
        }
};
```

**for example:**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="wrap4">1</div>
  <div class="wrap4">2</div>
  <div class="wrap4">3</div>
  <div class="wrap4">4</div>
  <div class="wrap4">5</div>
  <div class="wrap4">6</div>
  <div class="wrap4">7</div>
</div>
```

**Result:**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="wrapList">
    <div class="wrap4">1</div>
    <div class="wrap4">2</div>
    <div class="wrap4">3</div>
    <div class="wrap4">4</div>
   </div>
   <div class="wrapList">
    <div class="wrap4">5</div>
    <div class="wrap4">6</div>
    <div class="wrap4">7</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**It works great**, but if the divs before the wrapping are in two rows instead of one, for example:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="wrap4">1</div>
    <div class="wrap4">2</div>
    <div class="wrap4">3</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="wrap4">4</div>
  <div class="wrap4">5</div>
  <div class="wrap4">6</div>
  <div class="wrap4">7</div>
</div>
```

The result will not respect the rows and it will move the 4 to the top row to complete a line of 4 divs, for example:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="wrapList">
    <div class="wrap4">1</div>
    <div class="wrap4">2</div>
    <div class="wrap4">3</div>
    <div class="wrap4">4</div> (this div belong to the row below)
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="wrapList">
    <div class="wrap4">5</div>
    <div class="wrap4">6</div>
    <div class="wrap4">7</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I make the code respect the rows?

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Maybe use `.unwrap()` is solution. First unwrapp all of them and then wrapp them based on your need

Comment: I'm doing that. the problem is after the unwrapping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iterate through your rows, performing the wrap only on children of each row:

```js
function Wrap(){
        var $rows = $('.row');
        for (var h = 0, r; r = $rows[h]; h++) {
            var $children = $(r).find('.wrap4');
            for(var i = 0, l = $children.length; i < l; i += 4) {
                $children.slice(i, i+4).wrapAll('<div class="wrapList"></div>');
            }
        }
};

Wrap();
```

```css
.row {
  background-color: silver;
  border: 3px solid red;
}

.wrapList {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 3px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="wrap4">1</div>
    <div class="wrap4">2</div>
    <div class="wrap4">3</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="wrap4">4</div>
  <div class="wrap4">5</div>
  <div class="wrap4">6</div>
  <div class="wrap4">7</div>
  <div class="wrap4">8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its a little bit class like js function. Use lower case function name instead (its just opinion)

Comment: Just copy/pasted that from the question.  I agree that generally, function names should begin with lowercase.

Comment: I'm having an error:

**Uncaught ReferenceError: r is not defined**

Comment: @ysanmiguel There is no `r` in above code, maybe check if you missed the `$`

Comment: It's weird: **$r.find is not a function** the Jquery is running, any ideas?

Comment: You're right there was a bug.  I fixed it in the snippet.

Comment: The other solution creates a conflict, yours works is perfect, so thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can select each row and then iterate through each row and look for `wrap4` class and use `wrapAll()`.

```js
function Wrap(){
  $('.row').each(function(){
    var $children = $(this).find('.wrap4');
    for(var i = 0, l = $children.length; i < l; i += 4) {
        $children.slice(i, i+4).wrapAll('<div class="wrapList"></div>');
    }
   });
};
Wrap();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="wrap4">1</div>
    <div class="wrap4">2</div>
    <div class="wrap4">3</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="wrap4">4</div>
  <div class="wrap4">5</div>
  <div class="wrap4">6</div>
  <div class="wrap4">7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just realise that this solution creates multiple <div class="wrapList"> so, it's not viable.

Comment: I am not sure about what do you mean by creating multiple ` <div class="wrapList">` ? The solution is wrapping div inside `wrapList` class.